difficulty adding real time iot devices to thingsboard
i have my network up and running. it is able to receive uplink from the iot device in question. i have also configured mqtt broker. i published and subscribed to the network server and is able to receive messages from the network server. The problem is that i am not sure how to add devices on thingsboard.
i used the desktop docker to download thingsboard and to get the server up and running.
So technically there is 2 problems. the more important one is how to add devices on thingsboard so that thingsboard can record real time data. secondly is why the telemetry data is not received on this device.
Here's what i tried: i have tried following the basic documentation, adding a device and trying to test the connectivity but i am unable to test the connectivity but when i subscribed to v1/devices/me/telemetry on mqtt client i am able to see the value that i sent.
This is the picture showing that the mqtt client received the message.

This is the telemetry i copied from the thingsboard server device and i used the access token.

As you can see the telemetry is not received

